# see when a folder's files were last updated

Tags: google-drive-api

In Google Script, the code

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("test folder").next();
Logger.log(folder.getLastUpdated());
```

logs the last time the folder's own information was changed, e.g. its name.

Is there a way to see when the folder's *contents* were last updated, without having to iterate through the folder? e.g. if someone has added files to the folder, I want to be able to see when that last happened.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great news! [Detect Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-changes) discusses what you want for this use case!

First, you'll need to retrieve the page token for the current state of the account. Once done, you can then use the token to call the [`changes.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list). Do note that this call lists all changes done on the authenticated account, so you still have to filter out the changes specific to the folder you want. One approach is to put it on a loop with an `if` condition.

Happy coding!

Comment: This definitely looks complicated. I'll have to do some research. Thanks for your response!

Comment: adjuremods, do you have any idea whether this technique is account-specific? Would I be able to detect changes made by _any_ user?

Comment: Using `changes` would be account-specific as it only lists changes made by the user. If you're looking for changes made by any authorized user, then [`Revisions`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions#resource) would fit this use case better. Calling the `Resources: list` API will return an array of `Resources` which has the details of the `lastModifyingUser`. I believe folders are treated as Files, so just set its `fileId` and I think you'll be good.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thank you!